# Using Word automation, is it possible to find out if the active document contains VBA code?

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-automation

Using Word Automation, I want to save the active document programmatically.  In Office 2007/2010, the document needs to be saved explicitly as "macro enabled" to preserve any VBA code in that document.

Rather than asking the user to choose, I would like my application to be able to determine if there is VBA code in the active document.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this can be determined via the `HasVBProject` property. For example:

```
If ActiveDocument.HasVBProject = True Then

    'Code to save as .dotm

Else

    'Code to save as .dotx

End If
```

For those who might stumble upon this post later, it is worth noting that this code should be placed outside the document being tested for the presence of macros (otherwise it would detect itself). Two often-used options would be to access the code from an external application or from a template stored in Word's Startup folder.